# Java array concat

Tags: java, parsing, lexer

So I am trying to implement a way for the code to return just num when a double-digit number is entered instead of printing num num. To demonstrate if you run '45 - 23+8' the output will return 'num num minus num num plus num' and I would like it just to print 'num minus num plus num'. How would I go about doing this?

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter string:");
        String lexerInput = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String entered: " + lexerInput);
        char[] ch = lexerInput.toCharArray();
        List<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        //String arrayName[] = new String[ch.length];
        boolean invalidToken = false;
    
        // Traverse the character array
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        
        switch(ch[i]) {
        case '-':
            //arrayName[] = "Minus";
            arrayName.add("Minus");
            System.out.println("Minus");
        // code block
        break;
        case '+':
            //arrayName[i] = "Plus";
            arrayName.add("Plus");
            System.out.println("Plus");
    // code block
        break;
        case '/':
            //arrayName[i] = "Divide";
            arrayName.add("Divide");
            System.out.println("Divide");
        // code block
        break;
        case '*':
            // arrayName[i] = "Multiply";
            arrayName.add("Multiply");
            System.out.println("Multiply");
    // code block
        break;
        case '(':
            // arrayName[i] = "Open Bracket";
            arrayName.add("OB");
            System.out.println("Open Bracket");
        // code block
        break;
        case ')':
            //arrayName[i] = "Closed Bracket";
            arrayName.add("CB");
            System.out.println("Closed Bracket");
    // code block
        break;
        case '.':
            //arrayName[i] = "Dot";
            arrayName.add("Dot");
            System.out.println("Dot");
        // code block
        break;
        case ' ':
            //arrayName[i] = "Space";
            System.out.println("Space");
        // code block
            break;
            default:
        
        
            // code block
        
            if(Character.isDigit(ch[i])){
                //arrayName[i] = "Num";
                arrayName.add("Num");
                System.out.println("Character is a number");
            }
            else{
                invalidToken = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid Character");
            }
            //System.out.println("Not a accepted operator");
        }
        if(invalidToken){
            System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
            break;
        }
            // Print current character
            System.out.println(ch[i] + " ");
        }
    
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(arrayName.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

this is my code as of right now

Comment: You'll have to remember whether the previous character was a digit.

Comment: The algorithm suggested by tgdavies and user16320675 is a good one.  An alternative would be to do a pre-pass, in which you replace any string of digits (using a regular expression such as `\d+`) with a single `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a bolean `isPrevNum` which keeps track of the last character, as soon as I get something other than a number and the previous value is a number I add `Num` to the desired array.

*Since the last number with this approach will get skipped, I added a check at the very end to see if the last character was a number or not and added `Num` if it's true.*

Here's the discussed algorithm updated in your code for your reference:

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter string:");
        String lexerInput = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String entered: " + lexerInput);
        char[] ch = lexerInput.toCharArray();
        boolean isPrevNum = false;
        List<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
    
        //String arrayName[] = new String[ch.length];
        boolean invalidToken = false;
    
        // Traverse the character array
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
        
        switch(ch[i]) {
        case '-':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[] = "Minus";
            arrayName.add("Minus");
            System.out.println("Minus");
        // code block
        break;
        case '+':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[i] = "Plus";
            arrayName.add("Plus");
            System.out.println("Plus");
    // code block
        break;
        case '/':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[i] = "Divide";
            arrayName.add("Divide");
            System.out.println("Divide");
        // code block
        break;
        case '*':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            // arrayName[i] = "Multiply";
            arrayName.add("Multiply");
            System.out.println("Multiply");
    // code block
        break;
        case '(':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            // arrayName[i] = "Open Bracket";
            arrayName.add("OB");
            System.out.println("Open Bracket");
        // code block
        break;
        case ')':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[i] = "Closed Bracket";
            arrayName.add("CB");
            System.out.println("Closed Bracket");
    // code block
        break;
        case '.':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[i] = "Dot";
            arrayName.add("Dot");
            System.out.println("Dot");
        // code block
        break;
        case ' ':
            if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");
            isPrevNum = false;
            //arrayName[i] = "Space";
            System.out.println("Space");
        // code block
            break;
        default:
            // code block
            if(Character.isDigit(ch[i])){
                //arrayName[i] = "Num";
                // arrayName.add("Num");
                isPrevNum = true;
                System.out.println("Character is a number");
            }
            else{
                invalidToken = true;
                System.out.println("Invalid Character");
            }
            //System.out.println("Not a accepted operator");
        }
        if(invalidToken){
            System.out.println("Invalid Expression");
            break;
        }
            // Print current character
            System.out.println(ch[i] + " ");
        }
        
        
        // Adds the last number
        if(isPrevNum) arrayName.add("Num");

    
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(arrayName.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```